# AngularJS is not releasing callback lock after $q.reject

Tags: angularjs

I have AngularJS code inside service that looks as follow :

```
function getData(id) {
        return $http.get(baseURL + "/id").then(function (resp) {
            return resp.data;
        }, function (error) {
            return $q.reject(error);
        });
    }
```

in the controller I have the follow code :

```
service.getData(id).then(function (resp) {
            //do something
        }, function(error) {
             toastr(error)
        });
```

when the callback complete successfully ,everything is ok
but when there is an error , I get the  toastr msg , but the page is stuck in loading , like the callback didn't finish

what am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

If it calls the toastr method, then the callback is fine and all this code is working correctly, so your problem must lie elsewhere.

What is it that makes the page loading? What happens in the toastr method?